# Angular e2e doesn't look for tag until timeout after route

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, protractor

I have just started to learn writing e2e tests. Im doing some tests at first page and everything works well (title, an h1 tag text, count of cards on  page). I have buttons on cards at first page for rotate to another page. I'm finding it by buttonText method and do `.click()`. It rotates the second page like i want. But after that rotating process I'm trying to test an h1 text on second page. But its not working and I get timeout error. where am i doing fault?
Here is the part of my code;

app-e2e-spec.ts;

```js
    it('should go to measures page', ()=>{
        expect(page.goToMeasuresPage()).toEqual("Measures");
    });
```

app.po.ts;

```js
    goToMeasuresPage() {
        this.clickShowMoreButton(); //a function to expand card for show buttons
        let button = element(by.buttonText("Measures"));
        button.click();
        let headline = element(by.css(".container .header h1")).getText();
        return headline;
     }
```

second page's html;

```html
    <div class="container">
        <div class="header">
            <app-back-button></app-back-button>
            <h1>{{ 'MEASURES' | translate }}</h1> //this pipe returns "Measures" text
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you show which timeout error you are receiving? There are [several different](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md) timeouts that can appear

Comment: @DublinDev "Failed: script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds" says my command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After each action on the UI protractor checks an angular property in your site to ensure the page is stable (meaning all the changes and loading have completed on the page).

This issue is caused because Protractor is detecting the angular page has not stabilized after your rotate action. You can try increasing the default wait in your conf to give your app some more time to load:

```
//30 second timeout
allScriptsTimeout: 30 * 1000
```

If you still receive the timeout there may be some polling action in your app which is preventing angular from recognizing it has completed loading. See this [thread](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/4584) for some additional info

Comment: i have an interval on page for check every 60 seconds if server has any new data. could this be the reason?

Comment: For sure that is the reason. Your page will never stabilize as it will never finish loading.  You have a couple of options to handle that. You can ask the devs to move the setInterval outside the angular zone, [see here](https://medium.com/@jarifibrahim/the-curious-case-of-protractor-and-page-synchronization-58b4e81366ac) or you can disable the check for the angular stability using `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`. The later option will mean you need to handle all your waits yourself

Comment: [Another source](https://christianliebel.com/2016/11/angular-2-protractor-timeout-heres-fix/) regarding the zones.

Comment: i stoped interval and everything works well now. thank you so much. Im reading this articles now for a better solution than deleting interval. I guess if you hadn't helped me, I would never have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add following line after you assign `let headline` in `goToMeasuresOage`

`browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.presenceOf(headline))`

Comment: I dont know if i done well but i searched ExpectedConditions on web and changed my function like that;
`goToMeasuresPage() {
    var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
    this.clickShowMoreButton();
    let button = element(by.buttonText("Measures"));
    button.click();
    let headline = element(by.css(".container .header h1"));
    browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(headline))
    return headline;
  }` but i still have same error